# Once you mount a file system, how do you use it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I understand that a file system can be visualized as a "tree" of files and directories. I also understand that "mounting" a file system means to placing or rooting that tree within an existing directory. https://askubuntu.com/questions/20680/what-does-it-mean-to-mount-something

With that said, I have mounted an implementation of python fuse that is similar to [this](http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/) one. When I run my implementation, it runs to the end of the init method and then just shows a blinking cursor. So fuse is getting mounted. I know that fuse is mounted because of what happens when I run $mount

```
$mount 
...
FuseHandler on /home/memsql/mount
```

So now that I've mounted fuse, how do I access the files.

The linked tutorial says

> You will see all files in /your/dir under /mnt/point and be able to
>   manipulate them exactly as if they were in the original filesystem.

How exactly do you do this? Can somebody show me, syntactically, how to instantiate and query Fuse? How do you perform a read or write? What does code that performs those operations look like?

Comment: It's a filesystem. Once it's running and mounted, you use it like any other filesystem (ext/ntfs/fat et cetera) - with the standard IO functionality of the language or tool of your choice.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the documentation, the reference?

Comment: @alKid I am having trouble finding documentation that explains this. Can you link to where I should look?

Comment: @l4mpi So how do you query it? Do I cd to the fuse /mount directory and then perform a file system like ls? And then Fuse will handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As l4mpi notes, you’ve now mounted a file system, so it will respond to the standard Unix file system API, and FUSE will handle the file system operations.  You can `cd` to it, `ls` in it, `read` or `creat` files in it, etc.